# Error: redirect_uri_mismatch. App Engine. java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

In console the JSON of my project the url uri is a correct --> `http://FracasoTotal.appsot.com/YoutubeLIST/oauthWindow.html`

But when I click in deploy appengine, and click in the login button, select my account and send this error:

[image: URI error]

In the console of Google the name, credencials, etc has correct, I don(t understand which is the problem.

```
public class YoutubeListView extends Composite{

    private static final Auth   AUTH = Auth.get();
    private VerticalPanel       mainPanel;
    private final Label         labelAccessToken = new Label("");


        public YoutubeListView(Map<String, Object> params) {

            mainPanel = new VerticalPanel();
            initWidget(mainPanel);

            final String YOUTUBEAUTH_URL = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth";
            final String YOUTUBECLIENT_ID = "176930466315-6jamfetq1pm40igg3rmjp49tcmt7mtp7.apps.googleusercontent.com";
            final String YOUTUBE_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"; 

            Button buttonYT= new Button("Loguea tu cuenta de Youtube");

            final Label labelYT = new Label("");

            buttonYT.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

                public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

                      final AuthRequest req = new AuthRequest(YOUTUBEAUTH_URL,YOUTUBECLIENT_ID).withScopes(YOUTUBE_SCOPE); 
                      AUTH.login(req, new Callback<String, Throwable>() {


                          public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {

                              Window.alert("No se puede autentificar " + caught.getMessage());

                          }


                          public void onSuccess(String token) {

                             labelAccessToken.setText(token);
                          }


                  });
                 }

            });
            mainPanel.add(buttonYT);
            mainPanel.add(labelAccessToken);
            mainPanel.add(labelYT);
        }
}
```